# Convert sqlclient.h to swift

Tags: swift, sqlclient

I'm trying to access a SQL Server with swift SQLClient.h Already using classes I access the classes, but I can not translate the objective-c code to swift. The original code is this:

```
SQLClient* client = [SQLClient sharedInstance];
client.delegate = self;
[client connect:@"server:port" username:@"user" password:@"pass" database:@"db" completion:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success)
    {
      [client execute:@"SELECT * FROM Users" completion:^(NSArray* results) {
        for (NSArray* table in results)
          for (NSDictionary* row in table)
            for (NSString* column in row)
              NSLog(@"%@=%@", column, row[column]);
        [client disconnect];
      }];
    }
}];
```

Could anyone make a swift? .I Am unable. I get errors with the completion

I got this:

var client = SQLClient()

```
client.delegate = self
client.connect("172.29.XX.XX:1433", username: "XX", password: "XXXX", database: "XXX", completion: {(success:Bool) -> Void in


    if success
        {
            client.execute("SELECT * FROM Users" , completion: {(results:NSArray) ->  Void in

                for (table:NSArray in results)
                for (row:NSDictionary in table)
                for (column:NSString in row)
                    NSLog(@"%@=%@", column, row[column])

            client.disconnect

            } )
        }


})
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I'd suggest you show us how far you've gotten. Also, have you added SQLClient.h to your [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77)?

Comment: Yes, I added SQLClient.h to bridging header. I added what I have achieved in the original message. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A couple of observations:

1. In your Objective-C code sample, you're using the singleton, so I assume you should do that in the Swift code, too:

   ```
   let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()
   ```

   You can also use `let` instead of `var`. Always favor immutability over mutability. Only make it mutable where you need it to be mutable.
2. Your `for` loops:

   - require braces
   - don't need the parentheses around the expression of the `for` loop, though
   - the `for` loop of a dictionary in Swift returns a tuple including both the key and the value (in Objective-C it was just the key)
3. When you call `disconnect`, that's a function, so I'd include the `()`.
4. You can use `NSLog` if you want, but in Swift we often use `println`. But instead of `printf`-style formatters, we'd generally use string interpolation (e.g. `"value = \(variable)"` where the value of `variable` will be inserted in that string.
5. As a minor observation, I'd be inclined to adopt the trailing closure syntax (which gets rid of those `completion` parameters, converted to just a closure after the function) and use implied types to clean up the code sample.

Pulling that all together, that yields something like:

```
let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()

client.delegate = self
client.connect("172.29.XX.XX:1433", username: "XX", password: "XXXX", database: "XXX") {
    success in

    if success {
        client.execute("SELECT * FROM Users") {
            results in

            for table in results as NSArray {
                for row in table as NSArray {
                    for column in row as NSDictionary {
                        println("\(column.key) = \(column.value)")
                    }
                }
            }

            client.disconnect()
        }
    }
}
```

Or, possibly something like:

```
let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()

client.delegate = self
client.connect("172.29.XX.XX:1433", username: "XX", password: "XXXX", database: "XXX") {
    success in

    if success {
        client.execute("SELECT * FROM Users") {
            results in

            for table in results as [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                for row in table {
                    for (columnName, value) in row {
                        println("\(columnName) = \(value)")
                    }
                }
            }

            client.disconnect()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController:  UIViewController,SQLClientDelegate
```

---

```
func error(error: String, code: Int32, severity: Int32) {
    println(error)
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! I've fixed some formatting in your answer, but I would recommend explaining what the code is supposed to do within the answer. Right now I get the feeling that it is similar to the other upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

`sharedInstance()` is a `anyObject`, you have to set `client` as a `SQLclient` in order to be able to set de delegate to self:

```
let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance() as! SQLClient
```